# Behavior of tf.group for GANs

Tags: tensorflow

Generally, GANs are trained by alternately training the discriminator and generator, ie:

```
for i in range(num_steps):
    sess.run(minimize_loss_D)
    sess.run(minimize_loss_G)
```

I'm curious if I could use `tf.group` to achieve the same behavior, ie:

```
op = tf.group(minimize_loss_D, minimize_loss_G)
for i in range(num_steps):
    sess.run(op)
```

Would this be equivalent, or is there something fundamentally different about running a grouped op than running multiple single ops consecutively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use tf.control_dependencies. I suppose grouping could work too, but that would be parallel updates of the discriminator and generator. In classical GAN architectures, you update sequentially not in parallel. At least from a theoretical point of view, it's important that each is updated sequentially.  Also, by using the control dependencies you significantly reduce the amount of memory needed for backprop. If Tensorflow attempted to do both operations in parallel, you would need to store gradients for both ops. Also in practice, using control dependencies is rather fast and should be faster than doing two session runs.

I typically construct the update like so:

```
    with tf.name_scope('optimize'):
        g_min = opt.minimize(model.g_loss, var_list=model.g_vars, name='g_op')
        with tf.control_dependencies([g_min]):
            d_min = opt.minimize(model.d_loss, var_list=model.d_vars, name='d_op')
    train_op = d_min
    #sess.run(train_op)
```